# jquery check if element has one parent and doesn't have another

Tags: jquery, dom, if-statement, parent, closest

I need to do a certain action if one of the clicked element's ancestors has class 'textbox' AND none of the ancestors have class 'mceExternalToolbar'. If an object has a parent 'mceExternalToolbar' then it most definitely has a parent 'textbox', but the converse is not true.

I'm using this:

```
$('#content').click(function(e){
var $eparent = $(e.target).closest('.textbox');
var $etoolbar = $(e.target).closest('.mceExternalToolbar');

// what's wrong with this if condition?
if($eparent.length==1 && !$etoolbar.length)
{
   //do something
}
});
```

I thought it was simple enough but it just doesn't seem to be working. `$etoolbar == NULL` is not valid jquery but when I use it in the condition, the condition at least runs the first time (gives an error in console though).

Is there something wrong with my logic or with the way I'm using jQuery?

### Edit

The HTML code is below, and I'll give a short explanation.

I have a content box in which I dynamically create textboxes (I'm using the tinyMCE rich text editor for each of them). There are times when a textbox becomes "activated" (i.e. tinyMCE creates a bunch of elements within the textbox element, including a div with class "mceExternalToolbar".) A person may click anywhere on the big content div, but only when they click on a textbox do I want to do a certain action. Additionally, only when their click is not in the mceExternalToolbar area of a textbox will I entertain their click.

```
<div id="content" style="top:195px; position:absolute; height:300px; width:600px;border: 1px solid black;">

    <!-- THE BOX BELOW WAS CREATED DYNAMICALLY -->
    <div id="textbox_1" class="textbox" style="top: 101px; left: 112px; cursor: move;" aria-disabled="true">
        <div id="textbox_1_menu" class="menu"> <!-- menu items --> </div>
        <div id="textareacontainer_1" class="textareaedit">
            <textarea id="textarea_1" class="tinymce" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
                <p>Testing this textbox</p>
            </textarea>
            <span id="textarea_1_parent" class="mceEditor defaultSkin" role="application" aria-labelledby="textarea_1_voice"></span>
            <div style="position:relative">
                <!-- THIS HERE IS THAT PARENT WHO, IF ANY OF ITS CHILDREN ARE CLICKED, I WILL NOT ENTERTAIN IT -->
                <div id="textarea_1_external" class="mceExternalToolbar" style="display: block; top: -28px;">
                    <a id="textarea_1_external_close" class="mceExternalClose" href="javascript:;"></a>
                    <table id="textarea_1_tblext" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr role="presentation">
                                <td class="mceToolbar mceLeft" role="presentation">
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END CONTENT BOX -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you post your HTML structure as well?

Comment: Can you show us html or make a demo on jsFiddle

Comment: I think you meant "ancestors"

Comment: I'd say your "run by the first time" is wrong, it gives a syntax error which breaks the code before entering the `if` block. You could use `null` instead (JS is case-sensitive), but that won't make much difference.

Comment: couldn't add a jsFiddle - there's too much stuff going on because I'm using tinyMCE which adds a lot of stuff dynamically. But I've edited the question to include the relevant HTML.
@Alexander, yes ancestors.

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather, you only want click events when a user has actually clicked into the textarea portion of `#content`. Correct me if I am wrong.

```
$('#content').on('click', 'textarea', (function(e)
{
    e.stopPropagation() // Stops click event bubbling up to other elements

    // Execute code, this will only be run if a user
    // Clicks on a 'textarea' element within `#content`
});
```

You asked what is wrong with your if statement. `!$etoolbar.length` is not a good check for the element having either null or undefined length. You can use this instead in cases where you want to check the existance of a variable.

```
if ( typeof $etoolbar !== 'undefined' )
{
    // Do stuff with $etoolbar
}
```

Comment: the [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property of a jQuery object is always an integer number.

Comment: tis true, but checking for the type of the variable in my eyes is an easier method, especially when it comes to debugging. Good info to add mind you.

Comment: Oh I see your example. `$etoolbar` on OP's case will be an empty jQuery object (with `0` length) when no elements are matched. `=]`

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying your logic, you want all `.textbox` which aren't descendant of `.mceExternalToolbar`.

Try this after generating your tinyMCE:

```
$('#content .textbox:not(.mceExternalToolbar .textbox)').click(function() {
    //do stuff
});​
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/USqqW/)

Or this if you need event delegation, as you said "dynamically added" (note that most plugin initializations are synchronous):

```
$('#content').on('click', '.textbox:not(.mceExternalToolbar .textbox)', function() {
    //do stuff
});​
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/USqqW/1/)

When an element is clicked, the click event will bubble up to the `.textbox` elements which I attached the listener to, which doesn't include the descendants of `.mceExternalToolbar`.

This way, any descendant from the `.textbox` which have the listener attached to through directly binding (first code) or match the selector for the delegated event (second code) will trigger the handler when clicked without having to check for a `.textbox` ancestor.

Comment: There's a difference in ancestral hierarchy there from what I think you're saying. But thanks this is a new technique to me. I'll look up on the :not selector!

Comment: No problem. `:)` The only difference I can think of is that my selector will include all descendants of `.textbox` **and itself**, which wasn't in the original code. It most likely won't make any difference, but if you don't want the `.textbox` element itself included, you can always add an `if ($(e.target).is('.textbox')) return;` to the beginning of the handler function (with `e` as the `event` function parameter). `=]`